# Python to temporarily unlock and lock Windows

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to download data from various websites but one site in particular is giving me trouble. I narrowed it down to the fact that it will not run when the computer is locked. Everything works fine if I run it manually or if I remote desktop, but if I schedule the task to run and then lock the computer it will not run properly.

Is there a way to add something to my script which will:

1. Unlock my computer
2. Run the selenium script
3. Lock my computer

Or maybe schedule a remote desktop session to create an active desktop? Anyone have some advice on how to accomplish this correctly?

Comment: Do you run Windows?

Comment: Sorry yes. Windows 10 on one PC and Windows 8 on another (it doesn't matter which one I use for this task, whatever is easier)